# Free Shipping Applied for all Products, How to Restrict for selected Products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, products, free-shipping

I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/sNAm2KiYkwo) for `free shipping`, but free shipping applies to all products. Almost tried 3 weeks, still not getting any single loop. Those who certified in Magento pls help.

## How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello @Rathinam, any luck ?

Comment: @Pawan nope....

Answer (score 0):

I have seen video on given URL and there is some issue and you need following changes.

1. Change attribute type form **Drop-down** to **Yes/No** and Set **No** to default
2. Select **Yes** form admin for product you want free shipping.
3. In action tab for Shopping Cart price Rule change condition like:

if **ANY** of these condition s are **TRUE**

Free Shipping is **Yes**

Hope Above will help, If need any help feel free to ask.

**Updates:**
For reference I have attached images:
[image: Attribute settings in admin]

[image: Shopping cart Rule]

Comment: Have you checked Free shipping is Yes in cart rule ?

Comment: https://snag.gy/UVuYPK.jpg

Comment: Yes I followed everything,

Comment: Please share screen shot of rule without this dropdown

Comment: https://snag.gy/xCtLaB.jpg

Comment: check the last one.

Comment: rule seems right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73695/discussion-between-pawan-and-rathinam).

Comment: you can try with attribute type Yes/No. I think you have added No value to existing attribute.Above solution is tested and working. try to re-index, flush cache

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73695/discussion-between-pawan-and-rathinam

Comment: nope, not working...